# SQL Server Stored Procedure Error Handling

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, error-handling

I have a stored procedure which is runs automatically every morning in SQL Server 2008 R2, part of this stored procedure involves executing other stored procedures. The format can be summarised thus:

```
BEGIN TRY
  -- Various SQL Commands
  EXECUTE storedprocedure1
  EXECUTE storedprocedure2
  -- etc
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
  --This logs the error to a table
  EXECUTE errortrappingprocedure
END CATCH
```

storedprocedure1 and storedprocedure2 basically truncate a table and select into it from another table. Something along the lines of:

```
BEGIN TRY
  TRUNCATE Table1

  INSERT INTO Table1 (A, B, C)
  SELECT A, B, C FROM MainTable
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
  EXECUTE errortrappingprocedure
END CATCH
```

The error trapping procedure contains this:

```
INSERT INTO 
    [Internal].dbo.Error_Trapping
    (
        [Error_Number],
        [Error_Severity],
        [Error_State],
        [Error_Procedure],
        [Error_Line],
        [Error_Message],        
        [Error_DateTime]
    )
    (
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER(),
        ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        ERROR_STATE(),
        ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
        ERROR_LINE(),
        ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        GETDATE()
    )
```

99% of the time this works, however occasionally we will find that storedprocedure1 hasn't completed, with Table1 only being part populated. However no errors are logged in our error table. I've tested the error trapping procedure and it does work.

When I later run storedprocedure1 manually it completes fine. No data in the source table will have changed by this point so it's obviously not a problem with the data, something else has happened in that instant which has caused the procedure to fail. Is there a better way for me to log errors here, or somewhere else within the database I can look to try and find out why it is failing?

Comment: Are you running the main Stored Procedure from a SQL Agent Job or from an Application/Service?

Comment: The main stored procedure is being called from an external application.

Comment: Do you have some kind of log in the external application to check if there was an exception or something? Is there any possibility that one of the stored procedures is deadlocked by any other transaction?

Comment: To log an exception in the external application I would an exception to be raised in SQL Server in order to pass it back. 

There might be a small possibility but a deadlock should be picked up by the TRY CATCH block.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `SET ARITHABORT` (see [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190306.aspx)). It must `ROLLBACK` in your case. Also the answer of @Kartic seem reasonable.

I recommned also to read about `implicit` and `explicit` transactions - I think that this is your problem. You have several implicit transactions and when error happeneds you are in the middle of the job - so only part is `rollbackеd` and you have some data in that tables.

Comment: The problem isn't with the transaction rolling back or not, although this is something I will definitely add in at a later date (this is a system I have inherited). The problem is that I am unable to determine what the error was that was causing the problem.

Comment: For that reason I recoomend you to use `TRANS` or `ARITHABORT`. In that case I think that you will receive ERROR for sure.
I also have similar issue with a "ghost" error. I think introducing transaction will "catch" error. Aslo check `implicit` / `explicit` transactions - I think that the source of "ghost" error is there.

Answer (score 0):

There are some type of Errors that TRY..CATCH block will not handle them, look here for more information https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296(v=sql.105).aspx . for such Errors you should handle them in your application.
also I think you might have transaction management problem in your application too.

Comment: I think this is the most likely reason as I have tested the TRY CATCH blocks in both the parent procedure and child ones, and they do work. Unfortunately this is a difficult one for me to test and give a definitive answer as I can't manually recreate the error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you completely. Below code is too big for comment. So posting as an answer for your reference. If this is not what you want, I'll delete it.

Can we add transaction handling part as well.

```
DECLARE @err_msg NVARCHAR(MAX)

BEGIN TRY    
BEGIN TRAN

    -- Your code goes here

    COMMIT TRAN    

END TRY    

BEGIN CATCH 
    SET @err_msg = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    SET @err_msg = REPLACE(@err_msg, '''', '''''')
    ROLLBACK TRAN  
    -- Do something with @err_msg
END CATCH
```

Comment: I'm not sure I explained myself very well to be honest! The problem isn't really whether or not the transactions are rolled back in the event of a failure, as regardless I will need to re-run the procedure manually which will truncate the data from the existing table before re-populating. The problem is that I am unable to pinpoint what's actually causing the procedure to fail in the first place.